# Reinstalled Linux, now I can't boot into Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, boot, grub, ubuntu-20.04

I have been dual booting Linux and Windows 10 for many years now. I have a separate hard drive for each operating system. I just reinstalled my Kubuntu 20.04 installation with KDE Neon 5.20.

Now no grub menu shows although it used to and I can't boot into Windows from my motherboard's boot menu. It's like the Windows installation disappeared. The install did not overwrite Windows 10 (the files are still there).

Answer (score 2):

Kubuntu 20.04 and KDE Neon are two different distros, however they are very similar and the instructions in this answer will work for either of them.

### GRUB menu does not appear

If the computer boots into KDE Neon automatically without showing the GRUB menu at all, sometimes you can press the manufacturer's BIOS/UEFI key at boot time and while in UEFI or BIOS mode from the firmware menus select the operating system you need. Common keys used are Esc, Delete, F1, F2, F10, F11, or F12. On tablets, common buttons are Volume up or Volume down. During startup, there's often a screen that mentions the key. If there's not one, or if the screen goes by too fast to see it, check your manufacturer's website.<sup>**[*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/boot-to-uefi-mode-or-legacy-bios-mode)**</sup>

If this doesn't work when the GRUB menu does not appear at boot time, immediately after the motherboard / computer manufacturer logo splash screen appears when the computer is booting, with BIOS, quickly press and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, which will bring up a GNU GRUB menu screen. With UEFI press (perhaps several times) the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to get to the GNU GRUB menu screen. Sometimes the manufacturer's splash screen is a part of the Windows bootloader, so when you power up the machine it goes straight to the GNU GRUB menu screen, and then pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> is unnecessary.

If this doesn't work when the GRUB menu does not appear at boot time, then try the answers to:

- [How to get to the GRUB menu at boot-time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time)
- [Dual-boot boot menu does not show up after installing Ubuntu 15.10 alongside Windows 10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/717904/dual-boot-boot-menu-does-not-show-up-after-installing-ubuntu-15-10-alongside-win)

---

### Boot Repair

From KDE Neon open the terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair  
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install -y boot-repair
sudo boot-repair
```

Open the Boot Repair application and select *Advanced Options* -> *Other Options* tab -> *Repair Windows boot files*. The boot flag should be placed on the same partition on which KDE Neon is installed. The partition on which KDE Neon is installed can be identified from the built-in KDE Partition Manager application.

[image]

If you're unable to select the *Repair Windows boot files* option because it's grayed out, refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/947346/how-do-i-boot-windows-10-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-3/947628#947628).

---

### Rescatux

[Rescatux](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/) is a free bootable live CD/USB that can repair GRUB and the Windows bootloader. Rescatux has a graphical interface with a menu of operating system rescue tasks. If your hard disk has the MBR partitioning format, you can select the *Restore Windows MBR (BETA)* option to repair the Windows bootloader. If your computer has UEFI firmware, you can select among the UEFI boot options.

**Boot options:**

- (>=0.41 beta 1) Update UEFI order
- (>=0.41 beta 1) Create a new UEFI Boot entry
- (>=0.41 beta 1) UEFI Partition Status
- (>=0.41 beta 1) Fake Microsoft Windows UEFI
- (>=0.41 beta 1) Hide Microsoft Windows UEFI
- (>=0.41 beta 1) Reinstall Microsoft Windows EFI
- (>=0.41 beta 1) Check UEFI Boot

**GRUB options:**

- (>=0.40 beta 11) Easy GNU/Linux Boot Fix
- Restore GRUB and GRUB2
- (>=0.31 beta 4) Update any GRUB2 menu
- Update Debian/Ubuntu GRUB menus

**Windows options:**

- Restore Windows MBR (BETA)
- Clear Windows passwords
- (>=0.31 beta 4) Promote a Windows user to Administrator role
- (>=0.41 beta 1) Reinstall Microsoft Windows EFI
- (>=0.31 beta 4) Unlock Windows user

**Password options:**

- Change GNU/Linux Password
- Regenerate sudoers file
- Clear Windows passwords

**Expert tools:**

- Boot-Repair
- GParted
- OS-Uninstaller
- Clean-Ubiquity
- PhotoRec
- TestDisk

[image]
<sup>**Rescapp is a nice wizard that will guide you through your rescue tasks.**</sup>

---

### How to make a Rescatux live USB from an Ubuntu-based distro

1. Install GParted partition editor with `sudo apt install gparted`.
2. Insert a USB flash drive and check if the boot flag has been enabled on the flash drive using the GParted application. Unmount the USB flash drive. Open GParted and select the USB flash drive from the menu list of drives. From the GParted menu select: *Partition* -> *Manage Flags* -> check *boot*.
3. It is **very important** to verify that the device that you are installing the Rescatux live USB to is indeed your flash drive, so that you don't overwrite any of your system or personal files which may make your operating system unbootable. In KDE Neon you can find the device name of the flash drive using the KDE Partition Manager application.
4. Unmount the USB partition device. Let's say the USB partition device is `/dev/sdc1`

   ```
    sudo umount /dev/sdc1 # replace sdc1 with the partition name of your USB drive
   ```
5. Change directories using `cd` to the path of the directory where the Rescatux iso file that you downloaded is located.
6. Write the Rescatux iso file to the USB flash drive. In the following command replace `rescatux_0.xxxx.iso` with the name of the Rescatux iso file you downloaded.

   ```
    sudo dd if=rescatux_0.xxxx.iso of=/dev/sdc # this command also works in Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 
    sudo sync
   ```

I have also been able to make a Rescatux live USB using the Startup Disk Creator (*usb-creator-gtk*) app.

### Windows 10/11 factory reset repair of the Windows bootloader

<sup>[source](https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/how-to-factory-reset-windows-10)</sup>

**Open Settings**

Click the Start Menu and select the gear icon ⚙️ in the lower left corner of the desktop to open the Settings window. You can also select the Settings app from the app list. Under Settings, click Update & Security to continue.

**Choose Recovery Options**

Click the Recovery tab and select *Get started* under Reset this PC.

**Save or Remove Files**

At this point, you have two options. You can either choose to keep your personal files and only remove downloaded apps and settings, or you can wipe everything and start from scratch. Each choice will also give you an additional setting to change.

If you choose *Keep my files*, apps and settings will default to what they were when the PC was brand new. This setting can be turned off by clicking the Change settings link and switching it off. If you choose *Remove everything*, there's also a way to remove your personal files while saving apps and settings. Click the Change settings link and toggle the Data erasure option to on.

**Reset Your Computer**

Once you decide what should be removed from the computer, hit Next and Windows will tell you what will be deleted before you make a final decision. If you selected *Keep my files*, you can look at a list of apps that will be removed with the reset.

Finally, click Reset to actually commit. Your computer will restart, and after several minutes, it will boot back up again. When you return to Windows, you'll see that whatever you selected to be removed has been wiped from the machine. If you backed up your files, they can now be restored to the machine.

Answer (score 0):

One of two things most likely happened:

1. When you reinstalled Linux it reformatted or wiped your boot partition, removing the Windows boot files (note that these are on a separate partition from your Windows installation)

   You'll need to get a Windows CD or USB drive and do a startup recovery, then you'll probably need to manually boot into Linux and reinstall GRUB.
2. Your boot partition is fine, but GRUB didn't detect Windows when it was generating the menu configuration.

   Install `os-prober` and `ntfs-3g`, then run `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`.